# How to get focused form control name in angular reactive forms with the help of ReactiveForms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

One way i tried is adding OnFocus event on the form control.

Is there any possibility to get it with the help of reactiveFoms itself.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you want to know what control the user is currently focused on? What's the end goal here?

Comment: Yup, I want to know the user focused control name. 

use case: 
There are 5 input form controls, sum of all the values not to exceed 100.
So, I'm trying to write a common custom validator for all the form controls.
Whenever user focuses on any input control if count exceeds 100 then want to show an error message on that focused input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment I don't see the relevance of determining focus on a control to validate such that 5 input fields don't exceed the sum of 100. So I propose we could use a common validator that does the work for us (checking all inputs in the group).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';

  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myForm = fb.group(
      {
        field1: [null],
        field2: [null],
        field3: [null],
        field4: [null],
        field5: [null],
      },
      { validator: this.myValidator }
    );
  }

  myValidator(group: FormGroup) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let a in group.controls) {
      sum += group.get([a]).value;
    }
    console.log(sum > 100);
    return sum > 100 ? { notValid: true } : null;
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxxmke?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It serves the purpose partially. But the only thing is validation message will be shown at common place.
In my case I want to show it on focused form control. If none of the formcontrol have focus then want to show message at common place.